# Unable to execute docker cp with path stored in a variable in a bash script

Tags: bash, docker, sh

I have a bash script that reads a csv file line by line.

After every reading each line it will execute `docker cp` command.

However when it is executed the script fails to copy the files in the container.

```bash
INPUT=FileIdsToRemove.csv
COPYDIR=/var/lib/mayan/document_file_storage
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read fileuuid
do
        echo "uuid : $fileuuid";
        docker cp mayan_app_1:/var/lib/mayan/document_file_storage/"$fileuuid" ./;

done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

output:

```bash
uuid : 87d46881-0839-4ae1-aa20-3a056c2848c1
Error: No such container:path: mayan_app_1:/var/lib/mayan/document_file_storage/87d46881-0839-4ae1-aa20-3a056c2848c1
```

I am able to copy each file when I execute docker cp in the terminal instead of executing the script.

`docker cp mayan_app_1:/var/lib/mayan/document_file_storage/0fd5196e-fd01-44f7-91dc-ef1c9c5408f4 ./`

Below is the csv file content for reference

```
fileuuid
c61bd18a-47ef-448e-a04c-fd95b40d70c5
79c473e3-2f16-444e-9fe7-e02ce53f046f
87d46881-0839-4ae1-aa20-3a056c2848c1
16b1dc1f-e10f-4681-896a-d8fb3c421d22
792b363c-fa23-4f07-85a6-daa33ec4c5bd
```

Comment: The script will read the fileuuid and insert it into the end of the path /var/lib/mayan/document_file_storage/"$fileuuid"

I tried like this too "/var/lib/mayan/document_file_storage/$fileuuid" and it did not work.

Comment: All we can conclude is what the error message already says; there is no file with that name in the container.

Comment: As an aside, you'll want to paste your script at https://shellcheck.net/ and fix the many beginner errors. [Quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and [don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: For debugging, I would as a first step do a `docker ls -l mayan_app_1:/var/lib/mayan/document_file_storage` before the copying; this would - among others - verify that the parent directory of the file is accessible.

Comment: As a next step, I would paste the `docker cp` command, which you claim that it works in your interactive shell, literally into your script (perhaps as the first line). Finally, I would print the `uuid` not with `echo`, but with `printf %s $fileuuid||xxd`, to see whether you have some weird characters. In particular, look out 0d characters.

Comment: Thank you i will try the debugging and let you know

Comment: A possible cause of the problem is that the `FileIdsToRemove.csv` file has Windows line termination (CR-LF) instead of Unix/Linux line termination (LF).  See [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/4154375) and [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/4154375).  Either change the line termination in the file or modify the shell code to remove the CR (e.g. `fileuuid=${fileuuid%$'\r'}`).

Comment: The code for saving and restoring `IFS` doesn't work in general.  See [Is it a sane approach to "back up" the $IFS variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264926/264812).  A much better option in this case is to replace `while read fileuuid` with `while IFS=, read -r fileuuid`.  See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file \(data stream, variable\) line-by-line \(and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 0):

The script now works. I summarized how it works below.

read csv file line by line run `$(echo "$fileuuid" | sed 's/\r$//' | tr -d '\n')";` and store the output in a variable, i think this is the filename without `\r` character.

run `docker cp mayan_app_1:/var/lib/mayan/document_file_storage/"$fileuuidclean" ./;` after cleaning the filename to copy the file into the folder.

Below is the new script.

```bash
INPUT=FileIdsToRemove.csv
COPYDIR=/var/lib/mayan/document_file_storage
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read fileuuid
do
        fileuuidclean="$(echo "$fileuuid" | sed 's/\r$//' | tr -d '\n')";
        docker cp mayan_app_1:/var/lib/mayan/document_file_storage/"$fileuuidclean" ./;

done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```